# React: axois.get items in reverse order

Tags: reactjs, api

i need to fetch data from the api in reverse order by id

```
axios.get('/API/items', {
        params: {limit: 8}
    })
    .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
            items: response.data.results,
            loading: false
        })
        })        
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is--if the API doesn't offer this functionality then you need to sort on the client side once you have the results. If it *does* offer this functionality then how to do so is API-specific.

Comment: i have controle of the api, is there a way to do it there?

Comment: Sort it? Get it from the DB like that?

Comment: Yes i found how to do it in the documentaition just needed to do   in view.py   `queryset = items.objects.all().order_by('-id')`